# If $f:(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and strictly increasing, then $f'>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

If $f:(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and strictly increasing, then $$f'(x)>0,\:\forall \; x \in (0,1)?$$

I know that in general, when $f:I\subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is a interval, the result is not valid, just take $f(x)=x^3,$ for all $x \in I=\mathbb{R}$. However, I would like to know if it is worth when $I=(0,1)$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569793/conditions-for-inverse-function-theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $f(x)=\left(x-\frac12\right)^3$, for instance. It is strictly increasing, but $f'\left(\frac12\right)=0$.

Comment: Is there any condition I can impose on $f$ for this to become true?

Comment: I don't think so.